# Jssor Slider: Can I add video?

Tags: jssor

I would like to add a video inside my image slider but I need to be able to have a play, pause and stop on the video as well as make that slide last longer than the previous slides.

http://www.piratesdinneradventureca.com/

```
<!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (39KB) or jssor.sliderc.mini.js (31KB, with caption, no slideshow) or jssor.sliders.mini.js (26KB, no caption, no slideshow) instead for release -->



<!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = jssor.sliderc.mini.js = jssor.sliders.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.slider.js) -->



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jssor.core.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jssor.utils.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/shadowbox.js"></script> 

<script>(function() { var s = document.createElement("script");s.async = true;s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function(){getYelpWidget("pirates-dinner-adventure-theater-buena-park","658","WHT","y","y","11");};s.src='http://chrisawren.com/widgets/yelp/yelpv2.js' ;var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);})();</script>
```

Shadowbox.init({



    initialWidth: "200px",



    modal: true



});

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var options = { $AutoPlay: true };


        var _SlideshowTransitions = [



        //Fade



        { $Duration: 1500, $Opacity: 2 }



        ];







        var options = {

            $Loop: 1,   

            $AutoPlay: 1,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false


            $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000



            $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3



            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false



            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500



            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20



            $SlideWidth: 687,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container



            $SlideHeight: 324,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container



            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0



            $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1



            $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.



            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).



            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1



            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)







            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not



                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow



                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow



                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random



                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false



            },







            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not



                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance



                $ChanceToShow: 0,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always



                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1



                $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1



                $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0



                $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0



                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1



            },







            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {



                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance



                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always



                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1



            }



        };



        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);







        //responsive code begin



        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes



        function ScaleSlider() {



            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;



            if (parentWidth)



               jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);



            else

                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end



    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need something like this
http://www.jssor.com/demos/video-gallery.html

for source code, there is a html page in examples-jquery directory called video-gallery.source.html,
find this directory in jssor download package.

Comment: Could you post a related snippet of code, just in case the link ever dies?

Comment: Do you think the video gallery will work with the current jssor slider?

Comment: Please download jssor.slider.fullpack.zip, you will see an example with source code 'demos-jquery\video-gallery.source.html'

Comment: I was able to get insert the video and get it to play but I can't figure out how to get the controls? Also, how to get that slide to last longer?

Comment: Hi Jssor, can you offer any recommendations?

Comment: @jssor what about now in 2022 with slider 28.1.0? how to use youtube video and images with this current version?